# How to get updates from the input field in Django

Tags: javascript, html, django

I have this code in template

```
{% block content %}
<script>
    function onChange(event) {
        console.log("log")
    }
</script>
<h3>List</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Filter by..." onchange="onChange(event)" value={{ searching_value }} >
```

But it doesn't seem to work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @schillingt mentioned, the argument of `onChange` is a [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event). So you should treat it like one :)

```html
{% block content %}
<script>
    function onChange(event) {
        console.log(event.target.value)
    }
</script>
<h3>List</h3>

<input type="text" placeholder="Filter by..." onchange="onChange" value="{{ searching_value }}"/ >
```

Comment: Still the same..

Comment: @rikkatti do you know that `onchange` is triggered after focusing out the input? You have to click somewhere else to trigger that, only then `onchange` would be fired. If you need a reaction after each press of any key try `onkeydown`.

Comment: woooooooow, it s really working xD
thanks so much!

Comment: Glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

The value from the event should be accessed via `event.target.value` as per the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onchange). You can't access `this.value` how you are. `onChange` should accept an `event` argument and you pass the reference to the function for the `onchange` attribute.